# What's the most efficient way to convert a DataTable to an object[,]?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

I have a bunch of `DataTables` that need to be converted to `object[,]` arrays (*not* `object[][]` arrays). What's the most efficient way to do this in terms of performance?

I know I can do this by building my `object[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count]` initially, then looping through rows and parsing each row into a place in the array, but I'm fairly sure there's other methods such as using Linq or System.Data-specific features such as `dataRow.ToItemArray()` which may be more efficient.

My `DataTables` are of variable sizes, and contain both Dates and Numbers which need to be formatted appropriately, in addition to strings.

For example, if one of my data tables contained

```
Id    Name    Date                 Value
1     Rachel  1/1/2013 00:00:00    100.0000
2     Joseph  3/31/2012 00:00:00   50.0000
3     Sarah   2/28/2013 00:00:00   75.5000
```

then I would want an `object[,]` array containing the exact same data (ideally with headers), but with formatted Dates and Values

```
arr[x,0] = row[x].Field<int>("Id");
arr[x,1] = row[x].Field<string>("Name");
arr[x,2] = row[x].Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString("M/d/yy");
arr[x,3] = row[x].Field<decimal>("Value").ToString("C2"); // Currency format
```

Comment: Using LINQ doesn't magically speed up things.

Comment: By "more efficient", are you looking to improve the time complexity of your algorithm (like O(n^2) to O(n)), or just a constant factor improvement?

Comment: Why don't you include 'before' and 'after' data in your post?

Comment: @SteveWellens Sure, it's been added

Comment: There is no way of getting multidimensional array (`object[,]`) using LINQ. Multidimensional array does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: "converted to object[,] "  "contain both Dates and Numbers which need to be formatted appropriately"   That's confusing, if you have an array of objects, you don't get formatting.  Did you want everything converted to formatted strings and then objects?  I think you'll be hand-coding this stuff.

Comment: @SteveWellens I've added an update to my question. The library this array is used with exports the data based on the data type. In most cases, formatted data usually gets passed in as a string prior to exporting, but there are times when the data should be something other than a string, such as ints

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically we need:

1. Allocate memory for `object[,]`

   We cannot do much here.. we need to ensure we allocate memory once and not re-allocate it again. So it's obvious we need create array at once, without using operations like `List.Add(...)` which internally re-allocate memory blocks.
2. Then, we need to copy objects from row items into multidimensional array. We could not use `Buffer.BlockCopy` here as we work with objects. Naturally we can not rely on any `memcpy`-like behavior, as CLR for each object needs either copy its reference, or do unbox->copy in heap->box for value types. So, the simplest way will be just for.. for.. style.

So, looks like most performance solution here is the intuitive one:

```
public static object[,] Convert(DataTable dt)
{
    var rows = dt.Rows;
    int rowCount = rows.Count;
    int colCount = dt.Columns.Count;
    var result = new object[rowCount, colCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        var row = rows[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
        {
            result[i, j] = row[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```